# Hiding a bottom button on a special <div> part

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a button that I am showing at the bottom of the mobile pages.

It is a book now button. When I click on the button request goes to the form.

I don't want the Book Now button on the request form.

Here is the CSS code of the button

```
    .bookNow {
color: #ffffff; /* You can change font color */
font-family: inherit;
font-size: 14px;  /* You can change font size */
font-weight: bold;
width: 100%; 
background-color: #008489; /* You can change color button */
cursor: pointer;
display: none;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 3px;
letter-spacing: 0.8px;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 10px 3%;
z-index: 10;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
}


@media (max-width: 991px) {
    .bookNow {
    display: inline-block;
    display: block;
}
```

I use the code below to show on the page.

```
<div><a href="#booking_box" class="bookNow">Booking</a></div>
```

I want to hide this button on the below div

```
<div id="booking_box">
here we have the form
</div>
```

How I can do this with CSS or jquery?

Answer (score 1):

First set the id of the `<a>` to have an `id="booking_box_button"` and then add an onclick handler.

```js
const bookingBox = document.getElementById('booking_box_button');
bookingBox.onclick = function() { 
  bookingBox.style.display = 'none';
};
```

This will force it to stay hidden. If you want to have it show up again when the user moves on the page you can add something like this:

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  bookingBox.style.display = 'block';
});
```

Comment: once clicked it hides but when go up down, it still stays hiden.

Comment: probbaly need to get height till the part i wna to hide than getting the height of the div that i wan to hide than show for the rest.

Comment: See update to handle a change on the user scrolling.

Comment: ın case we click on the button works you roslution. but for only moving on th epage no. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: i see also that started to show on normal size also. normally we were showing that button only on mobile size